# How to create a custom JOOQ Record in MockDataProvider?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I want to return a mocked result for the query:

```
return dslContext.fetchExists(
                    dslContext
                        .selectFrom(CARDS)
                        .where(CARDS.CARD_ID.eq(cardId)));
```

The returned value is

```
+---------+
|exists   |
+---------+
|true     |
+---------+
```

[Mocking Connection](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.17/manual/sql-execution/mocking-connection/#implementing-mockdataprovider) has code examples on how to create a record from a generated Record class (like `CARDS`). How to generate a custom record for the return value of `select exists (... some query ...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This manual page shows [how to create arbitrary `Field` references in jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/), e.g.

```java
Field<Boolean> exists = DSL.field("exists", SQLDataType.BOOLEAN)
```

That's just one way to do it (probably the simplest). There are many others. There isn't any fundamental difference between this kind of `Field` and a generated one.

Of course, you could also just reproduce the `exists` expression instead:

```java
Field<Boolean> exists = DSL.exists(...);
```

Or really, just any dummy expression.